# COSMOS DB Issue when query with SQL statement

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I query the status data from Azure Cosomos DB, I encountered a problem and can't find solution.
Code:

```
public static async Task<List<StatusData>> GenStatusData()
        {


            var sqlQueryText = $"Select * from (SELECT c.task,c.status, count(c.task) as countnum FROM c group by c.status, c.task ) as e order by e.task";
            QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
            List<StatusData> models = new List<StatusData>();
            //Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CrossPartition.OrderBy.OrderByQueryResult.get_Rid()

            var queryResultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<StatusData>(queryDefinition);
            while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<StatusData> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                //Console.WriteLine(currentResultSet.Count);
                foreach (StatusData model in currentResultSet)
                {
                    models.Add(model);
                    //Console.WriteLine("\tRead {0}\n", model);
                }
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(models);
        }
```

Issue Encountered:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Underlying object does not have an '_rid' field.
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CrossPartition.OrderBy.OrderByQueryResult.get_Rid()

Comment: //Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CrossPartition.OrderBy.OrderByQueryResult.get_Rid() this commented line causing the issue?

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace and details of the error you are encountering?

Comment: The issues is caused by: FeedResponse<StatusData> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();